# Non clustered index on combination column vs each and every column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, database-administration

wt is the difference b/w creating a **non** clustered index on combination of 5 columns and seperate **non** clustered index for each of these 5 columns?

in a user query ,some times it uses any of the 3 columns in fileter.For some other queries it may use some of the 2 columns etc..in this case is it wise to use a single index for all the 5 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to create seperate index on,each searchable column as it will make write performance substantially worse

You can create one index for 5 columns.

Check out this link which tells you the [best practices to create a index](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/indexes-in-sql-server-20052008-best-practices-part-1/)

**NOTE:-** It also depends on  your `where` clause and `group by` clause of how frequently you are using the,

Comment: in a user query ,some times it uses any of the 3 columns in fileter.For some other queries it may use some of the 2 columns etc..in this case is it wise to use a single index for all the 5 columns?

Comment: I am not pretty sure about this but if you want to check it I would recommend you to look for the execution plan for both the cases. You will surely get your answer!! :)

Comment: You can use execution plan for checking what different indexing schemes offer to you. That would be a much smarter approach!!